# insert data from angularjs to Mysql using PHP

Tags: php, angularjs

I am trying to make a simple function in order to insert data from a form in angularjs to the Mysql database using PHP. The display data works fine but the insert doesn't work, is any body know how to fix it?

that's the angularjs code:

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.controller('usercontroller' , function($scope, $http){


$scope.insertData = function(){
    $http.post(
        "insert.php",
        {
            'name' : $scope.name,
            'age' : $scope.age,
            'email' : $scope.email
        }).success(function(data){
            alert(data);
             $scope.name = null;
            $scope.age= null;
            $scope.email= null;

            $scope.displayData()
        });

}
```

and that's the PHP code insert.php

```
<?php

$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root" , "" , "users");

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

if(count($data)>0)
{
 $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection , $data->name);
 $age = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection , $data->age);
 $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection , $data->email);
 $query = "INSERT INTO 'myusers' ('name', 'age', 'email') VALUES ('$name', '$age', '$email')";



 if (mysqli_query($connection , $query)) {
  echo "New record created successfully";
  } else {
  echo "Error: xxxxx";
   }
   }
   ?>
```

and the error is:

```
    angular.js:15570 TypeError: $http.post(...).success is not a function
at Scope.$scope.insertData (app.js:13)
at fn (eval at compile (angular.js:16421), <anonymous>:4:150)
at callback (angular.js:28954)
at Scope.$eval (angular.js:19396)
at Scope.$apply (angular.js:19495)
at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (angular.js:28958)
at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js:2)
at HTMLButtonElement.v.handle (jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js:2)
```

Comment: Use `.then()` instead of `.success()` - It is deprecated

Comment: i already tried also with .(then), the error is gone but i got another issue. when i press submit it shows me (the following is displayed on localhost) [object object] 

and nothing inserted to database

Comment: may be there is something in PHP code because there is a warning 

Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in C:\xampp\htdocs\crud\insert.php on line 6
Error:

Comment: The `$http.post()` returns a promise and the response object is different from how it worked with `.success()`  - It should be something like `$http.post(...).then(function( response) { var data = response.data; ...... };`

Comment: @YourCommonSense This is a mysql question (also). Look at their syntax again. They're not using the correct quotes. Least, the "mysql" tag should be added. I know they used "mysqli" but that was a minor detail.

Comment: @mido Your query failed. Use `mysqli_error($connection)` against the query.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner may be. but in this case it shouldn't be tagged with angular. these two technologies are never connect with each other. The angular code doesn't talk to mysql. it does talk to php. so it is either angular-php problem or php-mysql problem . but such a thing as angular-mysql problem just doesn't exist.

Comment: @YourCommonSense Ok. Well, I just thought I'd say that. They can take it from here :)

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner sry i am new in those stuffs, you suggest to use mysqli_error($connection) instead of mysqli_query($connection , $query)) ?

Comment: @mido No, replace `echo "Error: xxxxx";` with something like `echo "Error: xxxxx" . mysqli_error($connection);` and you will see the error. Remove the quotes from `'myusers' ('name', 'age', 'email')`.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I did what you suggested, the record is added in the database but null without info just empty record with age 0

Comment: @mido Well, least we're getting somewhere. If this is an angular question, I am not your guy for this.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner thx for you anyway :)